# Avoiding repetitive code in multiple similar methods (C#)

Tags: c#, design-patterns, generics, delegates

Greetings everyone!

I have a set of a few (and potentially will have dozens more) of very similar methods in C#. They all built on almost identical pattern:

```
ResultObjectType MethodX(...input parameters of various types...)
{
  nesting preparation code here...
  {
    {
      resultObject = ExternalClass.GetResultForMethodX(input parameters of MethodX);
    }
  }
  nesting result processing code here ...
  return resultObject;
}
```

Repeating/identical parts:  *ResultObjectType, preparation code, result processing code*.

Different parts: *ExternalClass method to call, input parameter set (number of input parameters, their types).*

**Important: I am not in control of the method signatures – cannot change them.**

I am trying to avoid repeating all blocks of similar code with something like this:

```
ResultObjectType MethodX(...input parameters of various types...)
{
    return  UniversalMethod( 
                   new ExternalMethodDelegate(ExternalClass.GetResultForMethodX),
                   input parameters of MethodX...);
}

ResultObjectType UniversalMethod (Delegate d, input parameters of various types...)
{
    nesting preparation code...
    {
        {
           resultObject = 
              (d as ExternalMethodDelegate)(same input parameters as above);
        }
    }
    nesting result processing code...
    return resultObject;
}
```

So far I only managed to make it work in this manner in case where all parameters have the same known type at the time of coding. After a number of attempts to tackle this problem with generic delegates I am starting to think this is not possible to achieve. Even when my code compiles, it does not work at runtime. Any takers? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is your pre and post processing code exactly identical and whether they do any compuattion around the input params? Are the input params across all the methods identical in type and order>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example using generic delegates:

```
int MethodY(int something, int other)
{
    return UniversalMethod(() => GetResultForMethodY(something, other));
}

string MethodX(string something)
{
    return UniversalMethod(() => GetResultForMethodX(something));
}

T UniversalMethod<T>(Func<T> fetcher)
{
    T resultObject;
    //nesting preparation code here...
    {
        resultObject = fetcher();
    }
    //nesting result processing code here ...
    return resultObject;
}
```

If ResultObjectType is always the same then you can remove all `T`s.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much Porges!

Answer (score 0):

*Repeating/identical parts: ResultObjectType, preparation code, result processing code.*

You should concentrate to make this parts as isolated as possible.

Another approach is code generation.