# Avoid repetitive code in Objective C

Tags: c++, objective-c, refactoring

I have two very similar methods in a C++ class. The only difference is the Objective-C methods that get called inside:

```
void MyClass::loadFromImage(UIImage *image)
{
    // ... Prepare dictionary and error

    GLKTextureInfo* info = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithCGImage:image.CGImage options:options error:&err];

    // ... Use GLKTexureInfo to load a texture
}

void Surface::loadFromImage(const char* imageName)
{
    // ... Prepare dictionary and error

    GLKTextureInfo* info = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithContentsOfFile:path options:options error:&err];

    // ... Use GLKTexureInfo to load a texture
}
```

How can I combine these two methods to reduce redundant code?

I am hoping to do something similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892050/avoiding-repetitive-code-in-multiple-similar-methods-c), but not sure how the syntax should work out in Objective-C. Thank you for help!

Comment: Objective-c does not have generics. You can't implement what they suggest in that thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

> // ... Prepare dictionary and error

and

> // ... Use GLKTexureInfo to load a texture

with methods that can be used by both versions of `loadFromImage`.

Yay code reuse!