# Avoiding repetitive method implementation in C#

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns, delegates, json.net

I'm having several class wherein i need to parse json object. I see the initial looping of this json object is pretty much same in all classes except sub methods.

For example, in Class1.cs

```
private static void FindObject(JToken token)
{
  switch (token.Type)
  {
      case JTokenType.Array:          
         JArray array = token as JArray;
         array.ForEach(a => FindObject(a));
         break;           
      case JTokenType.String:
         token.Replace(GetNewImgTag(token.ToString()));
         break;
      case JTokenType.Object:
         token.Children().ForEach(t => FindObject(t));
         break;
       case JTokenType.Property:
         JProperty prop = token as JProperty;

         if (prop.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array)
         {
             FindObject(prop.Value);
             return;
         }

         prop.Value = GetNewImgTag(prop.Value.ToString());
         break;
      default:
         throw new NotImplementedException(token.Type + " is not defined");
  }    
}

private static JToken GetNewImgTag(string text)
{
   ...
}
```

and Class 2.cs is

```
private static void FindObject(JToken token)
{
  switch (token.Type)
  {
      case JTokenType.Array:          
         JArray array = token as JArray;
         array.ForEach(a => FindObject(a));
         break;           
      case JTokenType.String:
         token.Replace(ReplaceLinks(token.ToString()));
         break;
      case JTokenType.Object:
         token.Children().ForEach(t => FindObject(t));
         break;
       case JTokenType.Property:
         JProperty prop = token as JProperty;

         if (prop.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array)
         {
             FindObject(prop.Value);
             return;
         }

         prop.Value = ReplaceLinks(prop.Value.ToString());
         break;
      default:
         throw new NotImplementedException(token.Type + " is not defined");
  }    
}

private static JToken ReplaceLinks(string text)
{
   ...
}
```

If you compare both classes, FindObject() is pretty much same except child method call. I need to implement this in several class. I'm trying to avoid this multiple duplicate method creation.

Can anyone suggest a better way to design this?

I saw similar post here but i'm unable to apply this delegates to my scenario.

[Avoiding repetitive code in multiple similar methods (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892050/avoiding-repetitive-code-in-multiple-similar-methods-c)

Comment: why are you not able to apply the delegate. the method will change to `FindObject(JToken token, Func<string,JToken> getValue)` and applied `prop.Value = getValue(prop.Value.ToString());`

Comment: For `case JTokenType.Property:`, why don't you check whether the value is a string?  It could be an integer or nested object or date or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straightforward way is to identify the different part, and make that a delegate you pass into a separate function.

Here's a working example.

```
public static class MyTokenReaderUtilities
{
     public static void ConvertEachProperty(JToken token, Func<string, JToken> convertString)
     {
        switch (token.Type)
        {
            case JTokenType.Array:          
               JArray array = token as JArray;
              array.ForEach(a => ConvertEachProperty(a, convertString));
              break;           
           case JTokenType.String:
             token.Replace(convertString(token.ToString()));
           break;
          case JTokenType.Object:
              token.Children().ForEach(t => ConvertEachProperty(t, convertString));
              break;
          case JTokenType.Property:
              JProperty prop = token as JProperty;

              if (prop.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array)
              {
                ConvertEachProperty(prop.Value, convertString);
                return;
              }
              prop.Value = convertString(prop.Value.ToString());
              break;
          default:
             throw new NotImplementedException(token.Type + " is not defined");
       }  
     }
}
```

Now, in class 1:

```
private static void FindObject(JToken token)
{
   MyTokenReaderUtilities.ConvertEachProperty(token, GetNewImgTag);
}
```

And in class 2:

```
private static void FindObject(JToken token)
{
   MyTokenReaderUtilities.ConvertEachProperty(token, ReplaceLinks);
}
```

Comment: looks like refactoring topic, therefore I would suggest [book](https://martinfowler.com/books/refactoring.html) from Martin Fowler